# getResourceAsStream returns null inspite of using servletContext()

Tags: java, file, servlets

This is a servlet that reads a .pdf and sends it as response. I don't understand why is it not working.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
        String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf");
        System.out.print(path);// this prints correct path
        InputStream is = null;
        try{
            is = sc.getResourceAsStream(path); // this is not working
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print(is);// it is null
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

        try{
        while((read = is.read(bytes))!= -1){  //exception is thrown here
            os.write(bytes,0,read);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
      }
```

Can anyone explain why is it not working, ispite of using this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/pdf/demo.pdf");

here is  the stack trace:

```
2/21/13 14:24:21:322 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.tgmc.servlets.DisplayOrder_PDF_Servlet.doGet(DisplayOrder_PDF_Servlet.java:42)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1449)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:323 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:288)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1016)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:639)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:324 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:325 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:325 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:325 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:325 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:325 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
[2/21/13 14:24:21:325 IST] 00000033 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

Comment: is your WAR file expanded? sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf"); this will work only if your WAR file is expanded

Comment: Show your stacktrace, what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @dj aqeel: NullPointerException

Comment: @pradeep simha: what do you mean by WAR file expansion??

Comment: @VishalAnand, it means a set of files not a single war file.

Comment: I mean, show the whole stacktrace in your question

Comment: @VishalAnand, see my answer, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Have you checked that the file exists? Please check whether the file exists: `File f=new File(path); if(!f.exists()){System.out.println("\n\n\nFILE DOES NOT EXISTS\n\n\n")}`

Comment: @Pradeep: you're misunderstanding the problem. The problem is that `sc.getResourceAsStream(path);` returns `null` while `sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf")` returns the correct path. The OP obviously want to use `sc.getResourceAsStream(path)` instead, exactly for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: @BalusC: Can you help me out. I have tried every thing and it still cannot find the file and returns null. As already mentioned the file is there but still it can't be read from sc.getResourceAsStream(path). but it works with sc.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try sc.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf")

and is it located under src/main/resources/WEB-INF/pdf ? file named .pdf and not .PDF?

edit: I tried this at home and it works for me.

```
    try{
        is = sc.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf"); // this works!
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: give you have a standard build, order.pdf should be in src/main/**webapp**/WEB-INF/pdf folder

(rather than src/main/resources...).

Vishal, can you give this another try using my code above and checking the folder structure?

Comment: Vishal, if no-one else answers, I can try out your code when I get home tonight... about 6 hours from now :)

Comment: this is the path value returned for me as the real path for the file : Y:\eclipse_projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\itext\WEB-INF\pdf\order.pdf. Do you know why is it that? Also I tried your code and it worked fine but as per my knowledge the files in the WEB-INF dir cannot be accessed this way,right? They are protected and should be accessed by realPath() method. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for your support :)

Comment: No worries, Vishal. Using real paths exposes your program to the underlying workings of the web container (in this case, Tomcat), and that generally isn't good. Plus you don't even really know if your pdf has been unpacked from the WAR to the filesystem yet. For this reason, it's preferred to use things like `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream` for accessing resources in WARs or `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` for accessing resources in JARs.

Comment: Im having a similar problem, though it only appears after the applications been idle for a long time (like over night). Have not found a solution, but will try request.getServletContext instead of the one from "this". Writing here in case I forget to come back and report success/failure

Answer (score 0):

I had the NullPointerException when calling GetResourceAsStream() on ServletContext too and have fixed so I post here for those who encounter the same issue. According to the document at
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html, the method getRealPath() will return the real path on the server filesystem, so calling `sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf")` as the code above will probably return `/opt/apache-tomcat/wtpwebap‌​ps/itext/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf` assuming /opt/apache-tomcat/ is the location of your tomcat on the server. The document also mentions that for the method getResourceAsStream(), we should pass in the relative path to the servlet context root starting with /. So for the code above, you should pass `/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf` insead of the real path to getResourceAsStream() method.

```
sc.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf")
```