# ServletContext: difference between interface vs implementation?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-container

[ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) interface docs:

> The path must begin with a / and is interpreted as relative to the current context root, or relative to the /META-INF/resources directory of a JAR file inside the web application's /WEB-INF/lib directory. This method will first search the document root of the web application for the requested resource, before searching any of the JAR files inside /WEB-INF/lib. The order in which the JAR files inside /WEB-INF/lib are searched is undefined.

I tested with Tomcat and it's not finding anything from WEB-INF/lib/*.jar files.
Can the implementation differ?
I have CommonRes.jar(in WEB-INF/lib) with this file inside:test.css

```
request.getServletContext().getResource("test.css");
request.getServletContext().getResource("/test.css");
request.getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/test.css");
```

All this getResource() variants returns null.

Comment: Your title is about interface versus implementation. How does that relate to the body of your Question? I don’t see the connection.

Comment: The text you quoted mentions that it searches within the `/META-INF/resources` directory when searching JAR files. Is your  `test.css` located in that directory inside the JAR? Can you include a listing of the JAR contents in the question? (Use  `jar tf  WEB-INF/lib/CommonRes.jar` to get the listing.)

Comment: @TimMoore, test.css is in root of CommonRes.jar. getResource() can't find in the root of a jar?

Comment: I've just tried copying various files into the locations you mention into one of my Tomcat 10 webapps. The only place where `request.getServletContext().getResource(xxx)` is not null is for paths under the root of the war (ie context path). The search works with or without a preceeding "/". It does not find resources in any WEB-INF/lib/xyz.jar (checked both the root of the jar and as "META-INF/resources/xyz.css").

Comment: @DuncG so I'm right, the docs of ServletContext interface it's wrong or the implementation it's wrong. Thank you for testing.

Comment: @BasilBourque the implementation it's not respected as in the docs of ServletContext interface.

Comment: @Blocked That would be a “bug” or flaw, not an issue of “interface versus implementation”.

Comment: @BasilBourque , give me a good title for this question. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29644548/1554397
@DuncG in the above link, it's saying that request.getServletContext().getResource(xxx) it's returning not null values only for path  under the root of the war or for path like "/WEB-INF/pdf/order.pdf" (so no insde jars). For loading resources from WEB-INF/lib/*.jar, we can use classloader. It's right?

Comment: @Blocked Yes, classloader.getResource(AsStream) is the way I normally access resources and makes code independent of servlet api.